# convert date to value in datetimelocal

Tags: php

```
      $START =  strtotime($START); // its a random date now
      $START_TIME = date("Y-m-dTh:i",$START);  // converting str to date in Y-m-dTh:i format

     <input  value='2018-06-12T19:30' type='datetime-local'>  // example how the value looks
     <input  value='$START_TIME' type='datetime-local'>
```

value='2018-06-12T19:30' <----
thats how a datetimelocal value looks.Any ideas how can I do it with variables?
Because if  I use " date(Y-m-dTh:i) " , i will get 2018-06-12CEST19:30, cause in the date the T meaning CEST, and  in the value hasn't got T, but I need it to print it. Sry for bad english

Comment: have you tried this date("Y-m-d\Th:i") ?

Comment: yeh ,it is work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh, just Y-m-d works, the h:i doesn't.

Comment: If you want 24 hour time, use H instead of h, so date("Y-m-d\TH:i")